# How would I compare UIButtons by their titles

Tags: iphone, uibutton

On an UIButton I have set the title like this

> [myButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

on another button I have set same title

> [myButton1 setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

by setting button tag I can easily compare. But how can I compare buttons by their title name?

Comment: what actually you want to do? make it clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the title value first..

```
NSString* str1 = [myButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSString* str2 = [myButton1 titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Now use the NSString function

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSString *)aString;
- (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *)aString

if([str1 isEqualToString:str2])
{
   NSLog(@"Equal");
}
else 
{ 
   NSLog(@"UnEqual");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[Button1.currentTitle isEqual:Button2.currentTitle]
```

Was it for iPhone 3.smth or 4.smth? The syntax changes between versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIButton's `currentTitle` property.

```
if([firstButton.currentTitle isEqualToString:secondButton.currentTitle])
{
//Do something

}
```